# Which engine for a 2D rpg for a beginner?

Tags: game-development, rpg

I am currently looking to build a small RPG as a hobby.

I already made a few games using Pygame but I find it tedious to start from scratch every time.

I also want to start using a proper game engine.

There currently is a huge discount on the Steam sale for RPG Maker VX Ace. Which promises easy and rapid RPG building. Yet, it looks like customising the scripts is a hell of a challenge. So I fear I might not learn that much from it.

The other thought I had was to use Unity with the [top down rpg starter kit](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/43566) . I think I would have much more versatility with that tool. However I have no experience in it and I really don't want to spend hours learning it for nothing. I didn't quite understand if the rpg starter kit provides a working demo game with which I can make some trials to learn how it all works and then either start from scratch or build on that base. What I don't want is an asset pack of scripts and sprites with instructions designed for experienced Unity users.

Any advice would be really welcome.  I would just ask that you consider the two options above in your reply even if  alternatives are welcome so that the question doesn't go to far off topic.

NB: I have Python programming experience but none for Ruby, C# ,or Javascript

Comment: Seems to be: the AssetStore page for that product contains what look like screenshots from two games.  But to be sure, you could do what I just did: submit a request to their customer service.

Comment: Have you settled the case and tried picked a tool?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [**GameMaker: Studio**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GameMaker:_Studio).

This piece of software costs $50 normally but I was able to get it for free through some sale. There is also a free version of GameMaker except it only allows you to have I think 15 sprites.

It has its own programming language called Game Maker Language or GML. This programming language is pretty simple and it gives you quite a bit of power.

With GameMaker you can also import maps that have been made from other pieces of software like Tiled.

I have used GameMaker to make several games including a couple platformer games and one RPG. It works very well and there is surprisingly quite a bit of non official documentation on YouTube. I would definitely recommend this piece of software if you want to make a simple RPG.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. It seems like the pro license is $149 per month. But the free version seems to go some way. I will keep the question open for now as I would like the feed back on the two options in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be surprised by RPG Maker. It's actually really simple. I would definitely recommend it to a beginner because scripting requires virtually no coding knowledge unless you build your own plugins.